# Number of labelled rooted plane trees

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, trees

I am trying to get the number of labelled rooted plane trees using symbolic method. For unlabelled rooted plane trees i use $\mathcal{T}=\zeta \times \mathcal{S}(\mathcal{T})$. Then

$t(z)=z\frac{1}{1-t(z)}\Rightarrow  t(z)^2-t(z)+z=0\Rightarrow t(z)=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2}$.

This is the GF for Catalan numbers multiplied by z. Hence, tn, the number of
rooted plane trees with $n$ vertices, is the (n-1)-rst Catalan number.

Now I'm having trouble for the labeled case, I know the result is $n![z^n]t(z)=n!\frac{1}{n}\binom{2n-2}{n-1}=\frac{(2n-2)!}{(n-1)!}$

Can anyone guide me to get the result using symbolic method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already showed that $[z^n]t(z) = \frac{1}{n}\binom{2(n-1)}{n-1}$ is the $(n-1)$st Catalan number. The number of labeled rooted plane trees is just this multiplied by $n!$ (accounting for the number of ways to label the vertices).

Using the symbolic method, this can be explained by noting that the GF for the labeled version also satisfies $\mathcal{T} = \mathcal{Z} \times \text{Seq}(\mathcal{T})$ (where the product and Sequence operations are for labeled GFs), so the GF is exactly the same as in the unlabeled case, so $n![z^n]t(z) = n! \frac{1}{n} \binom{2(n-1)}{n-1}$.

Comment: hello, thank you, I see that it was very easy, one more question, why the GF for labeled is the same in the unlabeled case?

Comment: @LuisAlexandher A labeled rooted plane tree satisfies the same recursion: it is the labeled product of a labeled root with a sequence of labeled rooted plane trees. Then you can note that this symbolic construction leads to the same GF construction by appealing to the theorems for labeled GFs.